# What items can be taken to Australia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia

This [Australian customs website](http://www.customs.gov.au/site/page4369.asp) lists a few prohibited articles for *import*.

When they say 'cannot be *imported*' does that mean goods only meant for commercial use (imported and then sold) ? Or does it also include broader things that people bring in for their personal use ?

This website also doesn't list seeds/meats of any kind which am pretty sure US and other countries explicitly ban. Is there a clear document on what *exactly* is not allowed to be brought to Australia by (non-citizen) individuals for personal use ?

Comment: Can you clarify where do you see "Cannot be imported"?

Comment: @Karlson The first bullet point from the site 'an absolute prohibition, which means that you are not allowed to import the goods in any circumstances, ' I guess I just substituted not allowed to import to cannot be imported

Answer (score 5):

You are looking at the list that is banned or restricted from import, and that applies under all circumstances.  It covers both commercial and personal use, though if you look at the list you shouldn't be falling afoul of many of them.

In addition to the list you found, you'll want to peruse [this list](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Ente/Brin/Can-I-bring-it-back) which tells you which items you need to *declare*.  This is where you find items like food, seeds and meat:

> Food, plants, animals and biological goods
>
> Declare all food, plant
> and animal goods, equipment used with animals, biological materials,
> soils and sand to Quarantine on arrival. If you don't, you could be
> given an on-the-spot fine or face prosecution.

The Customs inspector will then determine whether or not you can enter with the item(s), if it needs further inspection and/or fumigation in Quarantine, or if it can't enter Australia at all.

The majority of travellers will only need to be aware of a few guidelines:

- Items made from animal and plant byproducts will need to be inspected and sometimes quarantined.
- Processed foodstuffs are generally ok except for honey.
- Raw foodstuffs, especially fruit, are generally not ok.